# inet_ntop returns address that doesnt exist

Tags: c++, c, winsock2

```cpp
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, wchar_t *argv[]) {

    //init Windows Sockets
    //IResult
    int IResult = NULL;
    WSADATA wsaDataStruct;
    IResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaDataStruct);
    if (IResult != 0) // Error
    {
        //printf u are fucked;
        printf("Error: Winsock2 Init, %d", IResult);
        return 1;
    }

    //Result is output of getaddrinfo, hints is a helper struct
    struct addrinfo* 
        result = NULL, //Linked list of addresses
        * ptr = NULL, 
        hints = {};

    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    //Hostname
    char hostname[64] = {};
    gethostname(hostname, 64);

    IResult = getaddrinfo(hostname, "4500", &hints, &result);
    if (IResult != 0) { //Smth bad happened get Error
        printf("Error: Winsock2 addrinfo, %d", IResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 2;
    }

    //Loop addresses
    addrinfo* addr = result;
    while (addr!=nullptr)
    {
        char ip[16];
        inet_ntop(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_addr, ip, 16);
        printf("Address found: %s", ip);
        addr = addr->ai_next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am looping through the linked list of `addrinfo` structs and so far it returns one struct only which has an address of 2.0.17.148, while my machine has a local address of 192.168.2.1

I have only 1 network interface, and `addrinfo` returns a valid struct.

Comment: Are you sure that `result` is pointing to the interface address you expect? Or even to a valid `addrinfo` structure? Please try to show us a [mcve], and try to list all the interfaces available on your system.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i have only 1 interface, but gona post a full code

Comment: have you considered checking the return value of `inet_ntop` to see if there were any problems?

Comment: @ChrisTurner no errors, pointer to buffer is not a null

Comment: _"addrinfo returns a valid struct"_ What does this mean?

Comment: On an unrelated note, that's some weird mix of mostly C and some C++ you have there. With many inconsistencies. And only pointers can really be `NULL`, if you want to initialize an integer variable to zero use `0`.

Comment: Isn't `addr->ai_addr` a different type to what `inet_ntop` takes?

Comment: @user253751 it takes a void ptr

Comment: @user253751 you can recast socketaddr in to sockaddr_in

Comment: @AntonStafeyev but you cannot cast it to in_addr. (well, you can cast it, but you get gibberish)

Comment: @user253751 then in this scenario how would i translate address in to readable string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inet_ntop`'s argument should be a pointer to an `in_addr` (IPv4) or an `in6_addr` (IPv6).

You are passing it to a `sockaddr`, which will be a `sockaddr_in` for IPv4 or a `sockaddr_in6` for IPv6. (You won't get any IPv6 addresses because you only asked for IPv4 addresses using `AF_INET`). The sockaddr contains the family code, the port, and the address.

To get the `in_addr` you need to access it within the `sockaddr_in` structure: First cast `addr->ai_addr` to `sockaddr_in*`, then access the `sin_addr` member, then get a pointer to it.

```
inet_ntop(addr->ai_family, &((sockaddr_in*)addr->ai_addr)->sin_addr, ip, 16);
```

Note: this only works for IPv4 (AF_INET family). To support IPv6 as well, you need to check whether the family is AF_INET or AF_INET6, and use `sockaddr_in6` for AF_INET6, and allocate more space for `ip` because the addresses are longer.